# Datatables.js, usar algunos valores para formar galeria aparte

Tags: javascript, css, datatables, gallery

Buen dia, estoy trabajando con datatables.js... supongamos que tengo una tabla así, cuyos valores son recogidos de una base de datos.
Lo que quisiera es que esta tabla se cargue pero que esté oculta (solo por estilos), y luego solo usar ciertos valores para formar una especie de galeria.

Uso datatables.js para aprovechar las funciones como ordenar, filtrar y buscar; pero algunos datos los uso para formar la galeria, y los otros quedan ocultos solo para usar estas funciones.

```
            <table id="t_uno" style="display:hidden;">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Nombre</th>
                        <th>R1s</th>
                        <th>R2</th>
                        <th>R3</th>
                        <th>R4</th>
                        <th>R5</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                        <td>System Architect</td>
                        <td>Edinburgh</td>
                        <td>61</td>
                        <td>2011/04/25</td>
                        <td>$320,800</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                        <td>Accountant</td>
                        <td>Tokyo</td>
                        <td>63</td>
                        <td>2011/07/25</td>
                        <td>$170,750</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                        <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                        <td>San Francisco</td>
                        <td>66</td>
                        <td>2009/01/12</td>
                        <td>$86,000</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
          </table>
```

Además quiero darle un estilo de galería algo asi:

```
<style>
   ........
</style>

        <div class="card_catdos_imagenes ">
 
            <figure class="card_catdos_div_img">
                <img src="img/a.jpg" class="card_catdos_img aas">
                <div class="hover_catdos_img">
                     
                </div>
                <div class="hover_sup_catdos_img">
                     
                </div>
                <div class="hover_sup_text_catdos_img">
                    Aisfo Textola contenido
                </div>
                <div class="hover_inf_text_catdos_img">
                    Aifos Text Content
                </div>
            </figure>

            <figure>
            </figure>

            <figure>
            </figure>
                           .........
        </div>
```

Comment: ¿Quieres las imágenes que se encuentren dentro de las celdas de la DataTable para poder ser filtradas?

Comment: Creo que va a ser muy difícil lograr eso, DataTable solo maneja tablas y no otros formatos. Probablemente encuentres otra extensión que haga lo que necesitas [aquí](https://www.jquerycards.com/plugins/ui/filter-sort/)

Answer (score 0):

Estuve revisando en la web y me encontré con  [Vuetifyjs](https://vuetifyjs.com/)
. Es muy útil, tiene muchas herramientas.. e implementandolo con firestore queda genial